# Alternative for Redis SUB/PUB in Ruby for publish and subscribe events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

The problem I've run into is when using a free add-on for heroku I'm limited to 20 Redis connections. Each subscribe event is using a connection causing my application to max out with limited usage. The application is a messaging service using web-sockets. I understand refactoring for the reason of using a free hosting service may seem like a poor decision, however, this is the only thing Redis is being used for.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new connection to Redis for each subscribe, only one per process. Are you connecting clients directly to Redis?

Comment: Each subscribe would lock that Redis instance. Yes, I was creating a new subscribe for each websocket connection thus creating a new Redis instance for each one as well. Things started getting more complicated then I wanted when trying to share one subscribe for all websockets.

Comment: Well what you are doing is complicated and it only gets more complicated the more efficient you make it, this is how development works, haha.

Comment: Touché :) Fast, Good, or Cheap. I only get to pick two.

Answer (score 1):

Try faye or em-websocket for pub/sub and then you can use redis or postgres for persistence if needed.

http://faye.jcoglan.com/

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket

Comment: Faye looks really nice, but for my current situation I would like to avoid something that requires its' own server like Redis.

Comment: Aren't you already using Redis, in your question it says the problem is that you are limited to 20 connections.

Comment: This is the only thing I'm using Redis for so I would strip it out if another solution is found.

Comment: So Redis is a store, these other gems are websocket protocol implementations. They do different things. You can't just swap out Redis for Faye, Faye is not for storage. If you are ok with the messages disappearing as soon as the connection is closed and you don't need to store them then you can just use websockets without a store like Redis.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [EventAggregator gem](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/event_aggregator) which was really easy to use in place of the Redis Sub/Pub code.